python unittest own folder relative import ubuntu
There are similar questions but none of them have a completly sibling test folder with main.py in the src folder and none of them work. Currently I use the following approach
#project/tests/aaa/bbb/test_foo.py
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append("....")
from src.aaa.bbb import foo as foo
#...

and end up with a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

(I tested profoundly if the amount of points in sys.path.append("....") is correct)
Maybe I do not understand python but my folder structures (which I would like to keep) goes:
/project
  /src
    main.py
    /aaa
      /bbb
        foo.py
  /tests
    /aaa
      /bbb
        test_foo.py

I execute it in the project folder and for the normal not-test files that works fine.
A former Try was (in test_foo.py):
from ....src.aaa.bbb import foo as foo

This is the approach that works in the normal files but for the test files I got:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I tried it with and without the -m option.
Also with and without

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            unittest.main()



Usually you would set PYTHONPATH outside, instead of doing sys.path.append and importing from src. Have a look at Using pytest with a src layer

Where are you running from - what is the command line? You should never append to the sys.path - it's a matter of how you run/structure your code rather than the code itslef

@Mr_and_Mrs_D It is the normal terminal on Ubuntu if that answers your question. I opened the outermost folder ('project') but I do not want to be limited to this folder.

Could you provide the command line?

I suggest you to append to sys.path the absolute path of the folder project.
So the test_foo.py file becomes:
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append("/absolute/path/to/folder/project")
from src.aaa.bbb import foo as foo

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

To execute the script test_foo.py use absolute path of the script as in the following command:
> python /absolute/path/to/folder/project/tests/aaa/bbb/test_foo.py

The output is without import error (the import of foo from src.aaa.bbb is successfully executed):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK

PS: I have studied the problem of your instruction sys.path.append("....") but honestly I don't have found an exhaustive answer so I think that is better to add the absolute path to sys.path as I have done in this answer. At this link there is the documentation about absolute and relative imports.

I solved it with automatically fetching the abolute path and then sys.path.append(). However I still do not think that this should be the solution.
